# How to reference height of video in background in scale in filter_complex in ffmepg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have one video with resolution 480x360 (i.e. aspect ratio 4:3). I know how to change the aspect ratio of that video by inserting it on top of a 16:9 colored background. Here's a minimal working example of what I'm doing:

The following command generates a sample video with resolution 480x360 (i.e. aspect ratio 4:3)

```sh
ffmpeg \
  -v error -y \
  -f lavfi \
  -i testsrc=size=480x360:d=10 \
  testsrc.mp4
```

[image]

The following command uses the previously generated video, scale it, and put it on top of a video with resolution 720x405 (i.e. aspect ratio: 16:9).

```sh
ffmpeg
  -v error -y \
  -f lavfi \
  -i color=c=yellow:s=720x405 \
  -i testsrc.mp4 \
  -filter_complex '[1:v]scale=-1:405 [ovrl],[0:v][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:0:shortest=1' \
  output.mp4
```

[image]

As you can see above, the height of the colored background (i.e. `405`) is the same of the magnitude that is used in `scale` inside `-filter_complex`. I do this because I want the video that is being rescaled to fit perfectly on top of the colored background video so that the content of the video is fully displayed.

I very often find myself changing the height of the colored background and I wish that there's some way for `scale` in `filter_complex` to reference the height of the colored background, so that I don't need to change the height in two places. I know I can define a variable in various programming languages and call `ffmpeg` from there, as shown in the `bash` code block below, but I don't want to do this because of two reasons: (1) I don't want to depend on other tools to effectively use ffmpeg, (2) I want to learn more about the internals of ffmpeg.

```sh
my_height=405

ffmpeg \
  -v error -y \
  -f lavfi \
  -i "color=c=yellow:s=720x$my_height" \
  -i testsrc.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=-1:$my_height [ovrl],[0:v][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:0:shortest=1" \
  output.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use [scale2ref](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/scale2ref.htm.gz) filter:

```
ffmpeg \
  -y \
  -f lavfi \
  -i "color=c=yellow:s=720x405" \
  -i testsrc.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih[ovrl][v0];[v0][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:0:shortest=1" \
  output.mp4
```

When using `scale2ref`, there we have access to `main_h`.
The example uses `mdar` which equals `(main_w / main_h) * main_sar` (main_sar = 1).

---

Output:
[image]